# Chrome + CORS + cache - requesting same file from two different origins

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-s3, cross-domain, cors, chromium

I'm experiencing an issue with Chrome that I can't seem to fully understand, I'm curious if folks here have dealt with it before. This doesn't reproduce in Firefox. The steps are as follows:

1. Start incognito Chrome, navigate to https://foo.mysite.com and have the JS on the page make a GET ajax request to S3 for https://s3.amazonaws.com/mystuff/file.json . You get back a 200 response with:

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   x-amz-id-2: somestuffhere
   x-amz-request-id: somestuffhere
   Date: Tue, 14 Oct 2014 03:06:41 GMT
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://foo.mysite.com
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
   Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
   Cache-Control: max-age=86400
   Content-Encoding: gzip
   Last-Modified: Sun, 05 Oct 2014 00:29:53 GMT
   ETag: "fe76607baa40a793eb3b3cbd373a3fb8"
   Accept-Ranges: bytes
   Content-Type: application/json
   Content-Length: 5609
   Server: AmazonS3
   ```
2. Open a second tab, navigate to https://bar.mysite.com and have its JS make a GET ajax request to S3 for the same file https://s3.amazonaws.com/mystuff/file.json . Get back the following 304 response:

   ```
   HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
   x-amz-id-2: somestuffhere
   x-amz-request-id: somestuffhere
   Date: Tue, 14 Oct 2014 03:06:58 GMT
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://bar.mysite.com
   Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
   Access-Control-Max-Age: 3000
   Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
   Vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method
   Cache-Control: max-age=86400
   Last-Modified: Sun, 05 Oct 2014 00:29:53 GMT
   ETag: "fe76607baa40a793eb3b3cbd373a3fb8"
   Server: AmazonS3
   ```
3. Open a third tab, navigate to https://foo.mysite.com (the first site) and repeat the same steps as in 1. Chrome kills the response for CORS reasons and reports the following:

   ```
   XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://s3.amazonaws.com/mystuff/file.json. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://bar.mysite.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'https://foo.mysite.com' is therefore not allowed access.
   ```

What's the story here? This doesn't reproduce in Firefox. In Firefox I'm happily getting a 304 in both steps 2 and 3, which I would expect to see in Chrome as well.

A temporary workaround for this issue in Chrome is to set **Cache-Control: no-cache** on the file in S3, but then I'm forcing our clients to be re-downloading that file for no good reason, so it's not a real solution.

Is this intended and documented behavior? Is this a bug with Chrome? Any other thoughts?

Comment: This sounds like a proxy caching issue, except that the `Vary` header is set on the response, which should prevent the proxy caching issue. Can you inspect and share the response headers on response #3 (the failing response)?

Comment: The request is never received from the server because Chrome cancels the request. It shows provisional request headers and best, and those aren't super helpful.

I tried to see if perhaps capturing through chrome://net-internals would have led to seeing the response, but it also never makes it past the request there.

Comment: s/request/response/ in the first sentence above.

Comment: Cannot reproduce in Chromium 38.0.2125.106 (using netcat). Could you provide a demo page and website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is caused by [Chromium issue 260239](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=260239)

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why the 2nd request succeeds. Shouldn't it fail since the first response is cached?

Comment: It's definitely not clear why this only happens on the 3rd request.

Comment: This is happening to us in FF also. I believe it may be related to the lack of a Vary header.

Comment: This bug still alive in chrome 79

Answer (score 3):

I found this blog that help: [Add Vary headers to S3](https://kahwee.github.io/2016/06/12/how-to-make-vary-origin-in-aws-s3.html)
It helped by adding Vary headers to all XHR request.

I did run into a problem with html request (i.e. ) but I was able to overcome that by using hackround#2 described here:https://serverfault.com/a/856948

**TL;DR** of hack#2 is to use a "dummy" query string parameter that differs for HTML and XHR or is absent from one or the other. Example:
    `<img src="https://s3.png?x-request=html">`

Answer (score 1):

I just add a timestamp in request URL to force load the asset from S3 again, not from cache, such as `xxxx?timestamp=yyyy`

Comment: what if the request url is `https://{bucket-name}.s3.amazonaws.com/` and used as a form action, will this also work?