# Is/can a resource (js-file) from a CDN be shared across websites/browser tabs?

Tags: javascript, html, cdn

I'm not finding a definite answer on the web.

Lets say we have two sites both pull `jquery` from the same `CDN`.

- `pageOne.com` > `mycdn.com/jquery`
- `pageTwo.org` > `mycdn.com/jquery`

Now

1. I go to `pageOne.com`.
2. `jquery` is downloaded from `mycdn.com/jquery`.
3. I go to `pageTwo.org` (on second tab)

**Question:** 
Is `jquery` downloaded again for `pageTwo.org` (its the same CDN and the same jquery js file),
or can I use the browser cache for `pageTwo.org`? (i have already downloaded it when I was on `pageOne.com` before)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single cached version is used for both sites.  The URL for the jQuery library stays the same.  It doesn't matter what references it.

This is one of the main benefits of using a common CDN for common libraries... the fact that the user will probably have cached it already from some other site.

Answer (score 2):

Decentraleyes extension for [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/decentraleyes/?src=rating) and [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/decentraleyes/ldpochfccmkkmhdbclfhpagapcfdljkj) let you use the same cached file across all the visited sites... it caches the ressources files (JS mainly) to serve them from the local storage copy.

Otherwise this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26352083/chrome-cors-cache-requesting-same-file-from-two-different-origins) (requesting same file from two different origins) may be helpful in this situation.

And yes for chrome the cached files are served cross main different domains because the js file location (URL) is the same.

Links: [caching behavior](https://www.f5.com/services/resources/white-papers/caching-behavior-of-web-browsers), [cross origin requests](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409090), [cross domain cache](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-can-cross-domain-requests-with-different-origin-headers-be-cached-only-once/89645/5). [different-origin disk cache version](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-archive/2017Aug/0000.html), [caching with CORS](https://www.fastly.com/blog/caching-cors)